# Factoring a Polynomial Having No Rational Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For example: $$ x^3-6x^2+3x-10 $$

The rational roots test tells me that possible roots are $\pm\ 10, 5, 2, 1$. However, none of these roots will divide the polynomial into a more workable nominal.

How can I efficiently determine how to factor this without resources such as [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3-6x%5E2%2b3x-10)?

Thank you.

Comment: A cubic polynomial can only factor into the product of a linear and a quadratic factor (which itself might factor further). So if it has no linear factors, it's already irreducible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It has a linear factor; it just doesn't have a *rational* root.

Comment: I am assuming (based on the fact that the OP said "possible roots" and not "possible rational roots") that the OP wants to factor over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are correct

Comment: @Sven In that case, none of the tools mentioned below will give you  a factorisation over $\mathbb Q$, since you have proven yourself that **there is no rational root**

Comment: To rephrase some of the answers below, factoring over $\Bbb{R}$ amounts to finding real roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @JenniferDylan: No, it does not. $x^4+1$ has no real roots, but it does factor (over $\mathbf R$) into $(x^2+\sqrt 2 x+1)(x^2-\sqrt 2 x+1)$. It does if degree is at most three.

Comment: For that matter, $$ x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2 x + 2)(x^2 - 2 x + 2) $$

Comment: @tomasz Oh my bad, I meant factoring into linear factors.

Answer (score 3):

Turgeon already mentioned Cardano; here's how to apply it to your polynomial.

The first thing you need to do is to *depress* your cubic. "Depression" is the generalization of the usual "completing the square" done on quadratics. In particular, we make a variable substitution that removes the quadratic term.

In this case, from Vieta's formulas, we know that the mean of the roots is $6/3=2$, so we let $x=u+2$. This yields the polynomial $u^3-9u-20$.

Now we come to Cardano's piece of trickery. Cardano assumes that a root $u$ of $u^3-9u-20$ can be written in the form $u=r+s$. If we make that substitution, we obtain

$$(r+s)^3-9(r+s)-20=r^3+s^3+3(r+s)(rs-3)-20$$

From this, we obtain the system of equations

$$\begin{align*}
r^3+s^3&=20\\
r^3 s^3&=27
\end{align*}$$

Using Vieta's formulas again, we obtain the "quadratic" equation

$$(r^3)^2-20(r^3)+27=0$$

You should now be able to obtain $r$ and $s$. You already know that $x=r+s+2$ is one root of your cubic; divide that out of the original cubic, and solve the remaining quadratic. Done.

Answer (score 2):

By the intermediate value theorem, there's a root between $5$ and $6$.  You can use Newton's method to quickly find a close approximation to it.  Call that number $a$.  Then $x-a$ is a factor.  Use long division to find the quadratic factor.  The arithmetic may get a bit messy, but after that you're just solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: How did you figure that it has a root between 5 and 6?

Comment: @JozemiteApps : As I said: "by the intermediate value theorem". The value of the polynomial is negative when $x=5$ and is positive when $x=6,$ and polynomial functions are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can use:

- [Cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_formula#General_formula_of_roots);
- [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).